# PDAL Reader.las and Writer.las error

Tags: point-clouds, lidar

I am trying to read and write LAS (*.las) file using PDAL but getting the below warning messages and the reading/writing is not being done correctly by PDAL reader and writer for las files.

> (pdal pipeline readers.las Warning) C:/denoise\lake.las: Found invalid value of '0' for point's return number.
>
> (pdal pipeline readers.las Warning) C:/denoise\lake.las: Found invalid value of '0' for point's number of returns.

Code:
[image]

Errors:
[image]

Comment: You should add some code you've tried so far.

Comment: {
  "pipeline":[
   "C:/denoise/clear.las",
    {
            "type": "filters.outlier",
            "method": "statistical",
            "multiplier": 3,
            "mean_k": 8
        },
        {
            "type": "filters.range",
            "limits": "Classification![7:7],Z[-100:3000]"
        },
        {
            "type": "writers.las",
            "compression": "true",
            "minor_version": "2",
            "dataformat_id": "0",
            "filename":"C:/denoise/clean.las"
        }
  ]
}
This code works correctly for *.laz but not for *.las files.

Comment: I've figured out that the point cloud has been created from stereo pairs thus there will be no return of the beam information with the points.